# can not fetch data from sql table by the name of column . gives error . can only do the same by the number of column

Tags: c++, sql

it gives an error - "cannot convert parameter 1 from const char to int"

```
while(quer->Read()){                
label1->Text += quer->GetString("name")+"\n";
}
```

but this executes without any error

```
while(quer->Read()){                
label1->Text += quer->GetInt32(1)+"\n";
}
```

what is the problem ? how can I get data, entering the name of the column ?

Comment: SqlCommand^ comd = gcnew SqlCommand("select * from dbo.students order by name asc;", cond);

Comment: I mean to say is it the object of `SQLQuery` or something else?

Comment: SqlCommand^ comd = gcnew SqlCommand("select * from dbo.students order by name asc;", cond);
    SqlDataReader^ quer = comd->ExecuteReader();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As In your code:

```
while(quer->Read()){                
label1->Text += quer->GetString("name")+"\n";
}
```

you are using `string` in `GetString()` function.

But the declaration of this function is [GetString(int n)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For C++, With `Common Language Runtime(CLR)` you can refer [GetString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)

So you have to try the below code to get the string from the given column.

```
 while(quer->Read()){                
    label1->Text += quer->GetString(1)+"\n";
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks. but I mentioned in my question, that I can get data by GetString(1). I need to get data, by the name of column. Is it possible ? I was doing that some time ago. But now when I try to do the same it gives an error. what is the problem ?

Comment: @user3306372 sorry you have mentioned `GetInt32(1)` please change the question code

Comment: sorry. but how can i get data using the name of column ?

Comment: @user3306372 it is not possible with use of `SqlDataReader` as it is not documented in MSDN.

Comment: and how can it be possible ?

Comment: @user3306372 Please go through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx)